# Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\tmp\statistics.ivr'

Tags: windows-8, oculus

### Description of the problem:

I'm testing the `irisVR` Beta and I'm trying to launch some `cranium.obj` 3D model I have. I dragged and dropped the model directly on irisVR launch window and clicked launch. A terminal opens up for half a second and closes. Then nothing happens.

### Image 1 -- Iris launch window -- indefinite progress bar

[image: iris launch]

### Image 2 -- irisVR console.log

Here is the error I am getting in the `console.log`:

[image]

### Question:

What is causing this error, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nate here from IrisVR. Just wanted to let you know that for the next few versions (next few weeks), we have removed OBJ support. Your question makes me realize that our documentation needs some TLC and is misleading - I have added updating it to my task list and it should be amended by EOD tomorrow. Thanks for that!

You'll notice that the drop-zone graphic only includes the SketchUp and Revit icons. This won't last long, I promise! We are building a new system for handling the model geometry and optimizing it for VR and it broke part of the OBJ code. Ultimately, these changes are going to lead to some terrific improvements. Given our limited programming bandwidth right now, we had to pick two file formats to carefully maintain throughout this migration process and we'll pick up the pieces with OBJ ASAP

Thanks again for your patience and for using the app! In the meantime, give a SketchUp model a try :)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll check out the new version in a few weeks then.

Answer (score 1):

Another tester here - ran into the same issue on a fresh Bootcamp install, it's not isolated to the `*.obj` support that Nate mentioned as was able to recreate with both Sketchup and Revit models.

The current release (v0.2.4) appears to have some dependencies on the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 redistributable. If you don't have this installed, it will block the associated IrisVR `ModelConverter` from running and that `statistics.ivr` file from being generated. Unfortunately there is nothing logged to this effect, so took a bit of digging to find. You will however see a window flash up briefly, then close. This is the `ModelConverter` attempting to launch and quit.

To resolve, download and install [the redistributable from here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26999).